# Same code getting different results Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#

I have an app that I've been trying to re-write in a more organized fashion and making a custom class to handle my communications to be more readable and easier to "pass along" when needed. Anyways, basically it connects through an BleuI/O to an ArduinoBLE  device.
The Problem Statement:

I believe I am doing the same thing storing a port.ReadExisting() into a string variable that goes into a List, I do this with the same code but on one ocassion I get a List with various values (as intended) and in another ocassion I get a List with a single SUPERLONG string (like if all the strings were merged into1)

Here's the original code which was to scan for devices via BleuI/O and find the device I wanted (which had CMT in it's name).
[AFTER OPENING THE PORT, **NOTE COMMENT ON BREAKPOINT COUNT**]

```
private void dataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = "";
    connectedBleuPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
    
    if (!isConnected)
    {
        try
        {
            data = connectedBleuPort.ReadExisting();
            inBuffer.Add(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DATA RECEIVED IS: " + data);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        data = connectedBleuPort.ReadExisting();
        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { inputText.Clear(); });
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { inputText.Text = data; });
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    if (data.Contains("CONNECTED"))
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { closeBtn.Enabled = true; });
    }
}

private void updateComboBox()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inBuffer.Count; i++) //BREAKPOINT HERE HAS INBUFFER.COUNT AT 41
    {
        if (inBuffer[i].Contains("CMT"))
        {
            devicesComboBox.Items.Add(inBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label4.Text = devicesComboBox.Items.Count + " Devices Found"; });
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Scan button
    inBuffer.Clear();
    connectedBleuPort.WriteLine("AT+CENTRAL\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(75);
    connectedBleuPort.WriteLine("AT+GAPSCAN="+scanTime+"\r\n"); //Scan for 2 seconds, then 3, then 4 etc.
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { scanBtn.Enabled = false; });
    Thread.Sleep((1000*scanTime)+25);//Sleep while scanning, disabling button for scan time + 25ms 
    updateComboBox();
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { scanBtn.Enabled = true; });
    scanTime++;
}
```

That code above works as I intended, it scans via the BlueIO code and returns an array that populates the combobox.
Now to do this within a "communication handler" class, I believe I replicated the Code, however I always get 0 devices returned (the inBuffer count is always 1 really long string instead of various strings in a list)

HEre's the code for the new app with the Communication handler class:

```
private void scanBleu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bleuComboBox.Enabled = false;
    connect2BleuBtn.Enabled = false;
    if (dataHandler.isBleuConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning for Devices!");
        dataHandler.scanBleu(bLEScanTime);
        Thread.Sleep(1005 * bLEScanTime);
        List<string> devicesFound = dataHandler.returnDevices();
        //Thread.Sleep((1000 * bLEScanTime) + 25);
        Console.WriteLine("Found " + devicesFound.Count + " devices");
        if (devicesFound.Count != 0)
        {
            bleuComboBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string device in devicesFound)
            {
                if (device.Contains("CMT"))
                {
                    bleuComboBox.Items.Add(device);
                }
            }
            outputBleuConsole("**" + bleuComboBox.Items.Count + " DEVICES FOUND**");
            updateBleuScanBtn();
        }
        bLEScanTime++;
        bleuComboBox.Enabled = true;
        connect2BleuBtn.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }
    populateBleuCBox(dataHandler.getPortList());
    connect2BleuBtn.Enabled = true;
    bleuComboBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

The following 2 methdos are on my "Data handler class" which has the SerialPort stuff in it:

```
internal void scanBleu(int scanTime)
{
    //returns array of found devices.
    bleuInBuffer.Clear();
    //Scan
    bleuPort.WriteLine("AT+CENTRAL\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    bleuPort.WriteLine("AT+GAPSCAN=" + scanTime + "\r\n"); //Scan for x-seconds
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * scanTime);//Sleep while scanning, disabling button for scan time 
}

internal List<string> returnDevices()
{
    List<string> devices = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bleuInBuffer.Count; i++) //BREAKPOINT BLEUINBUFFER.COUNT IS ALWAYS 1
    {
        if (bleuInBuffer[i].Contains("Device"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device found!");
            devices.Add(bleuInBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Returning " + devices.Count + " devices");
    return devices;
}

private void BleuPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    bleuPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
    if (isModuleConnected) //if the connection was established, parse temperature readings
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Module connected, parsing Byte data");
            parseByteData();
            return;
    }
    try //try connecting and outputting to console. 
    {
        string data = bleuPort.ReadExisting();
        bleuInBuffer.Add(data);
        Console.WriteLine("DATA RECEIVED: "+data);
        StringDataNeedsParsing(bleuID, data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: In BleuPort_DataReceived when isModuleConnected you don't invoke ReadExisting. In your first code, you always invoke ReadExisting. It's a difference, I don't know if maybe relevant.

Comment: In returnDevices you search "Devices" and later also "CMT". In your first code, you only look for "CMT".

Comment: Victor, readExisting is invoked in the parseByteData() method (which is not shown here, not relevant to the error Im getting). Also thanks for noticing the CMT / Devices difference. They are 2 filters but tthe problem is still above that where the comment for the break points is (on one case I get 41+ string instances of devices found,  on the other I get the same list, but as a single string)

Comment: At first view, the main difference between implementations it's de delays in Thread.Sleep. Put a breakpoint after ReadExisting. It's possible that this function return one or multiple items depending of... I don't know, buffers, delays... If you can receive more that one item, look for any separator in the long string and do the split by yourself.